# Why can I not access my EC2 instance over HTTP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have created an EC2 instance (OpenVPN Access Server AMI) in the public subnet of a VPC. The AWS console shows a URL and a public IP address for the instance, but there is no response when I connect via HTTP, HTTPS or SSH.

Things I have checked:

- EC2 status checks are 2/2
- Security group allows all inbound traffic from my IP address
- Security group allows all outbound traffic to `0.0.0.0/0`
- Subnet of the EC2 is "Available"
- Route table has a route for `0.0.0.0/0`, which points to an Internet Gateway
- Route table is associated with the subnet of the EC2
- Internet Gateway is attached to the VPC

Here are the network ACL rules (I don't understand these):

**Inbound**

| Rule Number | Type | Protocol | Port Range | Source | Allow / Deny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| * | All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Deny |

**Outbound**

| Rule Number | Type | Protocol | Port Range | Source | Allow / Deny |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Allow |
| * | All traffic | All | All | 0.0.0.0/0 | Deny |

I created the VPC using Terraform (it is not the default VPC) so it is possible I have missed something.

What else can I try to diagnose and fix this?

Comment: Did you create a firewall rule to allow port 22 ?

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres Which firewall?

Comment: When I create EC2 instances to access via Jupyter notebook for Machine Learning, I always create firewall rules to allow ports 22 (SSH) and 8888 (Jupyter notebooks) for the Static IP address of the EC2 instance.

Comment: Do you mean the security group rules? Yes I have set those

Comment: @sdgfsdh check if your route table is associated with the public subnet where the instance is launched.

Comment: @samtoddler yes the route table is associated

Comment: @sdgfsdh can you share the output of this command <ssh -vvv -i key.pem ec2-user@ipaddres>

Comment: Aha! so with the username `openvpnas` I can SSH connect

Comment: I think that the HTTPS will work once I have done the one-time setup over SSH

Comment: @sdgfsdh exactly, when you login first time , it will do some basic setup and ask you few questions. Once done then you can access the UI for configuring further.